# subsetting world map to northern temperate latitudes ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a map of where my study sites are. All sites are in Northern temperate latitudes. To do this, I first load a world map, then set the y axis to only include northern temperate latitudes (between 23.5 and 66.5 degrees longitude).

```
#build map
world <- map_data("world") # we already did this, but we can do it again
map <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = world, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group))
map <- map + coord_map(ylim = c(23.5, 66.5))
map
```

However, this mixes things up at the top of the map, and also places a strangle black line just north of 50 degrees latitude. How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: It seems a problem with `coord_map()`. Replace it with `coord_quickmap()` works just fine.

Comment: This works, thanks @GL_Li, if you want to leave this as a formal answer I will accept it, otherwise I'll work it up tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice it and use a real projection as well:

```
library(ggalt)
library(ggplot2)

world <- map_data("world") 

ggplot() +
  geom_cartogram(
    data = world, map = world,
    aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group, map_id=region)
  ) +
  coord_proj("+proj=wintri", ylim = c(23.5, 66.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey - this looks great and I would love to implement this, however running this code returns: `Error in zero_range(from) : x must be length 1 or 2`

Comment: This is definitely associated with the `coord_proj("+proj=wintri", ylim = c(23.5, 66.5))` line, as the `geom_cartogram` function works fine and returns a map of the world.

Comment: Try installing ggalt from github. I also used the latest github ggplot2.

Comment: Gotcha. It took installing the github version of ggplot2 to get this to work. Thanks!